# Shuffle sentences pytelegrambotapi python

Tags: python, shuffle, sentence, py-telegram-bot-api

I am writing a bot on Python by telegrambotapi. Bot should send a random word from 2 lists.

My main question is, when sending a word from two lists, I want it to randomly shuffle the order of randomised words.

Here is a part of my code:

```
import telebot
def start(message):
 guilty = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5', 'name6', 'name7', 'name8']
 guiltless = ['nam1', 'nam2', 'nam3', 'nam4', 'nam5', 'nam6', 'nam7', 'nam8', 'nam9', 'nam10']
    bot.send_message (message.chat.id, str(random.choice(guilty) + str(random.choice(guiltless))
bot.polling()
```

When sending a message, I want it randomly shuffle the order of the sentence.

Comment: Note that `random.choice()` returns items of your lists which are strings, so there's no need to call `str` on them. Your question is unclear: what doesn't work as you expect here, and what different output do you expect?

Comment: Please enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to randomly change the order of the 'guilty' and 'guiltless' messages, you can [shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) the outputs of your choices:

```
message_parts = [random.choice(guilty), random.choice(guiltless)]
random.shuffle(message_parts)
bot.send_message (' '.join(message_parts))
```

I separated them with a space `' '` using `join`, you may change it with whatever you want.

Comment: File "C:\Users\khumoyun\Desktop\clooit\main.py", line 30, in play
    random.choice(guiltless)])))
TypeError: can only join an iterable

Comment: Oops.... I was not really awake when I answered :/ That's corrected!

Comment: I had one question.     message_parts = [random.choice(guilty), random.choice(guiltless)]
random.shuffle(message_parts)
bot.send_message (' '.join(message_parts)) Can i here don't shuffle 2 random words, but others should shuffle?